# RuntimeError: ERROR 010240 in Con operation in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, esri-grid-format, error-010240

I am dabbling with the resolution of the error says:

> RuntimeError: ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to

as attached as a screen shot. I am working with a DEM file and trying to generate raster based on the conditional values from  an excel file. As the excel file has about 15000 row, I need to generate about 15000 raster. I am very much disappointed when the script takes long time and at last it fails every time at different point and this has been happening from the yesterday.

I am just reading date and associated 3 temperature values from the excel and applying con operation on DEM argis grid raster to generate another raster. This process is repeated for all the dates i.e. rows in the excel file as attached.

My script is a below-

```
import arcpy,os,sys,shutil
from arcpy.sa import Con
from arcpy.sa import Raster
from openpyxl import load_workbook
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")


INPUT_TEMP_EXCEL_PATH = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
                        r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Ryan\Sept02ModularApproach\Temperature Model Data.xlsx"
                         )

INPUT_DEM_RASTER_PATH = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)    
                         r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Ryan\Sept02ModularApproach\DEM\dem_clip_11"
                         )
Second_Discrete_variable = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)   
                            10
                            )

OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)    
                         r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Ryan\Sept02ModularApproach\OutputRaster"
                         )

TEMP_FOLDER_PATH = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)    
                         r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Ryan\Sept02ModularApproach\Temp"
                         )

Second_Discrete_variable = float(Second_Discrete_variable)
Temp_Data = []
#Loading temperature data
temp_wb = load_workbook(filename=INPUT_TEMP_EXCEL_PATH, read_only=True)
temp_ws = temp_wb[temp_wb.sheetnames[0]]
for row in temp_ws.rows:
    rw = [cell.value for cell in row]
    Temp_Data.append(rw)

Temp_Data= Temp_Data[1:]

#Folder content deleter
def folder_content_deleter(folder_path):
    for the_file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            pass


#set temporary places, grid format needs a gdb for placing intermediate data
folder_content_deleter(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH)
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_folder_path=TEMP_FOLDER_PATH, out_name="ScratchData_solRaster", out_version="CURRENT")
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = os.path.join(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH,"ScratchData_solRaster.gdb")

#processing Second part
for tdata in Temp_Data:
        T1 = tdata[1]
        T2 = tdata[2]
        T3 = tdata[3]
        output_second = Con(Raster(INPUT_DEM_RASTER_PATH)<2573,T1,Con(Raster(INPUT_DEM_RASTER_PATH)<=2754,T2,T3))
        final_temp_raster = output_second+Second_Discrete_variable

        #save
        out_path = os.path.join(OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER,str(tdata[0]))
        final_temp_raster.save(out_path)

#Cleaning
if arcpy.Exists("in_memory"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
folder_content_deleter(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH)
```

My error in gist is-

> RuntimeError: ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to
>   C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\Ryan\Sept02ModularApproach\Temp\ScratchData_solRaster.gdb\ifthe_ras
>   with output format FGDBR.

The excel file I am using is https://www.dropbox.com/s/qacfhipo4ry7o2b/Temperature%20Model%20Data.xlsx?dl=0

My error-
[image: error]
N.B. I tried several thread here and in arcgis sites some of them are-

1. [What causes RuntimeError: ERROR 010240 saving after CellStatistics?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58816/what-causes-runtimeerror-error-010240-saving-after-cellstatistics)
2. [Why does CON statement give ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to (value) with output format GRID?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76541/why-does-con-statement-give-error-010240-could-not-save-raster-dataset-to-valu)
3. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124511/error-010240-with-output-format-grid

System specification:
[image: system specification]

---

---

### Update:

*I tried with different scratch and current workspace

*I tried with arcpy.gp.Times_sa(it stops after processing almost 3000 rasters) and arcpy.sa.Times(it stops after processing almost 1070 rasters)

*I tried with arcpy.TestSchemaLock

*I tried with setting output to tif format too.

I see that it stops and raises error when it processed and output exact number of 1070 grid files.
After some time wasting I came with the following-

```
import arcpy,os,sys,shutil,time,csv
from arcpy.sa import Con
from arcpy.sa import Raster
from openpyxl import load_workbook
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")


INPUT_TEMP_EXCEL_PATH = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
                        r"C:\test\Temprt.xlsx"
                         )

INPUT_DEM_RASTER_PATH = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)    
                         r"C:\test\dem_clip_11"
                         )
Second_Discrete_variable = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)   
                            1
                            )

OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) 
                         r"C:\test\myout"
                         )

TEMP_FOLDER_PATH = (#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
                         r"C:\test\mytemp"
                         )

Second_Discrete_variable = float('%.6f'%Second_Discrete_variable)
Temp_Data = [] # it is as list like [[19120515L, 5.673994, 4.899673, 2.826565], [19120516L, 7.585234, 6.915178, 4.927008],..............]

#Loading temperature data
temp_wb = load_workbook(filename=INPUT_TEMP_EXCEL_PATH, read_only=True)
temp_ws = temp_wb[temp_wb.sheetnames[0]]
for row in temp_ws.rows:
    d = []
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == None:
            pass
        elif cell.value == 0:
            d.append(0.000000)
        elif isinstance(cell.value, float):
            d.append(round(cell.value,6))
        else:
            d.append(cell.value)
    Temp_Data.append(d)

#process collected excel data
Temp_Data= Temp_Data[1:]
seen = set()
Temp_Data = [x for x in Temp_Data if x[0] not in seen and not seen.add(x[0])]# removing duplicate date

#Folder content deleter
def folder_content_deleter(folder_path):
    for the_file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

#gdb content deleter
def gdb_content_deleter(wrkspc):
    for r,d,fls in arcpy.da.Walk(wrkspc, datatype="FeatureClass"):
        for f in fls:
            print f
            try:
                arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(r,f))
                print "deleted scratch"
            except:
                pass

#set temporary places, grid format needs a gdb for placing intermediate data
folder_content_deleter(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH)
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_folder_path=TEMP_FOLDER_PATH, out_name="SDB_SR", out_version="CURRENT")
scr_db = os.path.join(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH,"SDB_SR.gdb")
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = scr_db

#processing Second part
counter = 0
for tdata in Temp_Data:
        T1 = float('%.6f'%tdata[1])
        T2 = float('%.6f'%tdata[2])
        T3 = float('%.6f'%tdata[3])
        out_folder_name = str(tdata[0])[0:4]
        out_folder = os.path.join(OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER,out_folder_name)
        if not os.path.exists(out_folder):os.mkdir(out_folder)
        arcpy.env.workspace  = out_folder
        out_path = os.path.join(out_folder,str(tdata[0])+'.tif') #like C:\\test\\myout\\1912\\19120515.tif'
        output_second = Con(Raster(INPUT_DEM_RASTER_PATH)<2573,T1,Con(Raster(INPUT_DEM_RASTER_PATH)<=2754,T2,T3))

        #apply map algebra if feature exists
        try:
            final_temp_raster = arcpy.gp.Times_sa(output_second, str(Second_Discrete_variable), "in_memory\\test_"+str(counter))
            qq = final_temp_raster.getoutput(0)
            qq=Raster(qq)
            final_temp_raster = qq

        except:
            pass
            try:
                #check if wait is of use
                time.sleep(15)
                final_temp_raster = arcpy.gp.Times_sa(output_second, str(Second_Discrete_variable), "in_memory\\test_"+str(counter))
                qq = final_temp_raster.getoutput(0)
                qq=Raster(qq)
                final_temp_raster = qq
            except:
                pass
                #write the errors into csv
                with open(os.path.join(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH,'error.csv'), 'ab') as error_file:
                    writr = csv.writer(error_file)
                    writr.writerow(tdata)
        counter+=1

        #save
        final_temp_raster.save(out_path)

        #cleaning
        if arcpy.Exists("in_memory"):
            arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
        gdb_content_deleter(scr_db)

#Cleaning againg completely
if arcpy.Exists("in_memory"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
folder_content_deleter(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH)
```

It is giving me pain for several days- please help!

Answer (score 2):

Al last I solved the problem! But waiting for more elegant solution, hope esri nerds can help.

My understanding that solved the problem:

1. Use separate scratch and output work-space
2. Using multiprocessing is imperative if raster to process is so
   many(I am obliged to Dan for this concept)- it is really helpful
   though slow in comparison to the other multiprocessing tasks- esri
   engineers can tell more about it
3. Be careful about locks.
4. Always clean the garbage in each work-space.
5. If given multiple raster to process then *arcpy.gp.Times_sa* can handle more than the *arcpy.sa.Times* can handle.Really it is absurd that deprecated tool is more powerful that the new one (i call it a nascent babe or at least an apple of Sodom)

My understanding about arcpy in raster processing at least in their grid format:

1. Arcpy can not handle task that involves more than 3000 raster at a
   stretch to process.

Below is my script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Author:Shariful Islam
#Contact: msi_g@yahoo.com

import arcpy,os,shutil,multiprocessing,re
from arcpy.sa import Con
from arcpy.sa import Raster
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
try:
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
except:
    raise Exception("install the openpyxl module in your python system")


#================================================================================================================#
#change below as it suits your system. try to make short all path below e.g. C:\OutputRsater  D:\InputTempFile.xlsx
#just change the paths i.e. right side of the equations below nothing else- be careful.



INPUT_TEMP_EXCEL_PATH =  r"C:\test\Temprt1.xlsx"
INPUT_DEM_RASTER_PATH =  r"C:\test\dem_clip_11"
OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER = r"C:\test\myout1"
TEMP_FOLDER_PATH = r"C:\test\mytemp"






#do not change below from here
#================================================================================================================#

Temp_Data = []
#Loading temperature data
temp_wb = load_workbook(filename=INPUT_TEMP_EXCEL_PATH, read_only=True)
temp_ws = temp_wb[temp_wb.sheetnames[0]]
for row in temp_ws.rows:
    d = []
    if len(row)>3:
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == None:
                pass
            elif cell.value == 0:
                d.append(0.000000)
            elif isinstance(cell.value, float):
                d.append(round(cell.value,6))
            else:
                d.append(cell.value)
        Temp_Data.append(d)

#process collected excel data
Temp_Data= Temp_Data[1:]
seen = set()
Temp_Data = [x for x in Temp_Data if x[0] not in seen and not seen.add(x[0])]# removing duplicate date

#Folder content deleter
def folder_content_deleter(folder_path):
    for the_file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

#folder deleter
def purge(dirpth, pattern):
    for f in os.listdir(dirpth):
        if re.search(pattern, f):
            pth = os.path.join(dirpth, f)
            shutil.rmtree(pth, ignore_errors=True)

#gdb content deleter
def gdb_content_deleter(wrkspc):
    for r,d,fls in arcpy.da.Walk(wrkspc, datatype="FeatureClass"):
        for f in fls:
            print f
            try:
                arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(r,f))
            except:
                pass 

#copy and group by year
def grouperByYear(input_folder_path, output_folder_path):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(input_folder_path, topdown=True, datatype="RasterDataset", type="GRID"):
        for filename in filenames:
            out_folder_name = re.findall(r'(?<=\g)\d{4}', filename)[0]
            out_folder_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path,out_folder_name)
            if not os.path.exists(out_folder_path):
                print "Creating and populating folder for year %s ......"%out_folder_name
                os.mkdir(out_folder_path)
            in_data = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
            ou_feature_name = 'g'+re.findall(r'(?<=\g\d{4})\d{4}$',filename)[0]
            out_data = os.path.join(out_folder_path,ou_feature_name)
            arcpy.Copy_management(in_data, out_data)


#processing Second part
def times_worker(times_range_list):
    #set temporary places, grid format needs a gdb for placing intermediate data
    #folder_content_deleter(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH)
    scratch_db_name = "Scratch_"+str(times_range_list[0][0])
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_folder_path=TEMP_FOLDER_PATH, out_name=scratch_db_name, out_version="CURRENT")
    scr_db = os.path.join(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH,scratch_db_name+".gdb")
    arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = scr_db

    #set output db
    out_db_name = "RData_"+str(times_range_list[0][0])
    #arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_folder_path=OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER, out_name=out_db_name, out_version="CURRENT")
    #out_db = os.path.join(OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER,out_db_name+".gdb")
    out_db = os.path.join(OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER,out_db_name)
    if not os.path.exists(out_db):os.mkdir(out_db)
    arcpy.env.workspace  = out_db

    for tdata in times_range_list:
            T1 = float('%.6f'%tdata[1])
            T2 = float('%.6f'%tdata[2])
            T3 = float('%.6f'%tdata[3])
            out_path = os.path.join(out_db,'g'+str(tdata[0]))
            outRast_name = "in_memory\\%s"%out_db_name
            arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(INPUT_DEM_RASTER_PATH,outRast_name)
            output_second = Con(Raster(outRast_name)<2573,T1,Con(Raster(outRast_name)<=2754,T2,T3))
            final_temp_raster = output_second

            #save
            final_temp_raster.save(out_path)

            #cleaning
            gdb_content_deleter(scr_db)            


def main(cu, worker, d_range):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cu)
    pool.map(worker,d_range,1)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    core_usage = 5 
    chunk_size = 1000
    needed_cpu = int(round((len(Temp_Data)/chunk_size),0)+1)
    offsetter = list(divmod(needed_cpu, core_usage))
    cpu_distribution = [core_usage]*offsetter[0]+[offsetter[1]]
    cpu_distribution = [cp for cp in cpu_distribution if cp!=0]#just remove zero
    temp_data_range = [Temp_Data[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0,len(Temp_Data),chunk_size)]
    print r"Doing raster math. It may take upto 3-7 hours even and may use your cpu at the heighest.\
          So stop using your cpu fo this time. Go and enjoy elsewhere, let me do the job for you!.........."    
    loopcnt = 0
    for cpu in cpu_distribution:
        temp_data_range_splitted = temp_data_range[loopcnt:loopcnt+cpu]
        if len(temp_data_range_splitted)>0:
            main(cpu, times_worker, temp_data_range_splitted)
            loopcnt+=cpu

        #Cleaning
        if arcpy.Exists("in_memory"):
            arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
        folder_content_deleter(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH)

    #group by year
    print "\nGrouping raster math output by year for you. It may take 1-2 hours at best.So stay tuned!........\n"
    grouperByYear(OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER, OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER)

    #delete unnecessary folders
    print "\nCleaning all unnecessary files........\n"
    purge(OUTPUT_TEMP_RASTER_FOLDER, r'RData_[0-9]{8}')

    print r"All jobs finished! Now you are ready for the further processing:)"
```