# Arcpy - Error 010240 - Con statement - can`t save raster dataset with output format GRID

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-010240

I am trying to set an "output path" in my Arcpy script in order to not have to repeat the path everitime I want to save a dataset after applying a tool.

So I set the output path like:

> output_path = "C:/PhD/output"

But Python is sending this error message:

> RuntimeError: ERROR 010240: could not save raster dataset to C:\PhD\output with output format GRID

I`ve had a look at the tips given by Slslam in his question bellow

[RuntimeError: ERROR 010240 in Con operation in arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210128/runtimeerror-error-010240-in-con-operation-in-arcpy)

So I have separated scratch and output workspaces and I have imported multiprocessing, but it is still not working, as ERROR 010240 keep being sent.

I am using ArcMap 10.2.

Can anyone shed light on this problem, please?

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy, multiprocessing
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/PhD/raster"
output_path = "C:/PhD/output"

# Set local variables
inRaster1 = Raster("slope_angle")

# Execute raster calculator to create a slope percentage raster showing values <= 9% and the remaining
#values set to zero

outRas1 = Con(inRaster2 <= 9, 1, 0)
outRas1.save(output_path)
```

Comment: Have you tried a different output type? `outRas1.save("C:/PhD/output.tif")`

Comment: Yes, and it works. But in reality the path is much much longer than "C:/PhD/output,tif", and in addition, the real script have many raster outputs. So I want to make my script more elegant, instead of having to write the entire output path every time I need to save a new raster dataset. Thanks!